# Textures disappear from Plane Meshes when the z dimension is translated

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I've discovered that when I construct a Plane `Mesh` with a `Texture` applied to it, if I translate the z dimension either positively or negatively (to avoid z-fighting) the texture disappears.

**Code that works (z value is not translated):**

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000);
geometry.translate( 2, 2, 0 ); // when the z value is 0 the stripe texture will show 
var stripe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(stripe);
```

**Code that doesn't work (z value is translated either positively or negatively):**

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1000, 1000);
geometry.translate( 2, 2, 2 ); // when the z value is translated either positively or negatively (other than 0) the stripe texture will not show up
geometry.translate( 2, 2, -2 ); // this one doesn't work either
var stripe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(stripe);
```

I am using an `OrthographicCamera` with a front frustrum of 0 and a back frustrum of 2000, so the positive values *should* show up. When I change the front of the frustrum to -100 (though I've heard one should avoid a negative front frustrum value, though I'm not sure why) then the stripes *do* show up when the z dimension is a value other than 0. What is going on here??

**Update:**
Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/sqzhdxv9/7/) where you can change the z value in the translate function and see the issue for yourself.

Comment: Probably the mesh is lipped by the near plane or far plane. How to you set the camera, especially the near and far plane? Is the z position of your mesh within the near and far plane?

Comment: Please demonstrate the issue in a live example. You can use this fiddle as a starter template: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/15337/

Comment: @Mugen87 - thanks for taking a look. I've posted a working fiddle of the problem above in an update. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @Rabbid76 - Thanks for having a look at this. Would a plane have a thickness that would cause this? I've posted a fiddle above - take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle works with negative z-value for `.translate()`. Your orthographic camera is in the center of the scene and looks along negative z-axis. Near plane of the camera is at 0, far plane is at 2000 (thus the camera can see everything in the range from 0 to -2000 along z-axis). When you set positive z for translation, you simply put the geometry (and the mesh respectively) out of the sight of the camera. At least, that's how your fiddle works for me. Possibly, I'm wrong and specialists, better than me in Three.js, will correct me.

Comment: No, you are absolutely right ;). The OP just have to transform the camera to a different position than the origin. E.g. if you set the position of the camera to `(0, 0, 100)` like in the following fiddle, you can see the plane with a positive z-value for the translation. https://jsfiddle.net/sqzhdxv9/16/

Comment: @prisoner849 - thanks to you and Mugen87 for your clear explanation. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll accept it. After these fixes, the problem still occurred in the context of the project I've been working on, but it seems there's a bug in how I'm assigning the z  value in a loop. I'll post a separate question about that...